# Event listener keyup + Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-listener

I have a hook I am trying to use to detect an escape keypress. I am getting a typescript error when passing a function into the event listener.

The error comes here `document.addEventListener('keyup', listener, false)` specifically on the `listener` function and is:

```
Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'KeyboardEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<Element>': locale, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist
```

```
Argument of type '(event: KeyboardEvent<Element>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-darkness-f905cn?file=/src/useEscapeKeyPress.ts

**Hook**

```
export function useEscapeKeyPress(action: () => void): void {
    const listener = useCallback(
        (event: KeyboardEvent<Element>): void => {
            if (event && event.key === 'Escape') {
                action()
            }

            return
        },
        [action]
    )

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', listener, false)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keyup', listener, false)
        }
    }, [listener])
}
```

If I hack the typescript by using //@ts-ignore I can see that the logic is working correctly however I cant seem to shake this error

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong: just don't pass the generic type param https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwG4wLzxMArgWwKZhQB0wATngIZR4CiANnvoQBQDkiSrAlANwBQHIhThwaSAlAAyCaATyk2AazwBPLAAdWAGhjM8SKAC4YAaVUAjEBVKjxhLsaQgEcNAD4YAbz4wYoSCAMRHQgAOZKqhoAhNz8AL68fEA

Comment: I have tried to remove the generic type, just having KeyboardEvent and still get the same error thats why its not clicking for me at the moment why. I created a sandbox with the same problem

Comment: Ok, I've removed my close vote. I see the error in the sandbox... but I cannot reproduce it anywhere else. Not in the playground, not in a project I just spun up with create-next-app. I do notice that you are using a ***very*** outdated Typescript version. You have 4.4.2, and you're mixing it with a brand new version of @types/react-dom. Maybe try updating to 4.9.5 or 5.0.3? I don't know why that would matter, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: Use just `(event: KeyboardEvent)` and remove the import for `KeyboardEvent` from react (as you're not using a react event here like you do with `onXYZ` attributes)

Comment: Man I feel silly, the import from react is what was causing it thanks @NickParsons